# PHP send plain text mail and force fixed-width charset

Tags: php, email, width, character-encoding, fixed

I want to force the reader's email client to display my php-generated **plain text** emails with a fixed width charset.
Thunderbird displays the email with a fixed width charset. However, Gmail and Outlook (and probably more clients) do not.

Is this a config setting with my mail server or something I'm doing wrong? 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

These are the headers I'm currently using:

```
    $header = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
    $header .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1; format=flowed\r\n"; 
    $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n"; 
    $header .= "X-Mailer: PHP" . phpversion() ."\r\n"; 
    $header .= "From: ihateoutlook@email.com\r\n";
    $header .= "Reply-To: ihateoutlook@email.com\r\n";
```

Comment: Correction: fixed width *font*, not *charset*. These are two different things. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot force the plain text message to use any specific font. The best you can do is send HTML email using the `monospace` font family.